# How to get the indices of similar valued numbers in a numpy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy, indexing, coordinates

My array is suppose:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.              
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0.        
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0.   
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0.  
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

There are two objects in the above image(array). I want to find the indices of the two objects. The array is not constant - it can vary and the number of objects can vary too. 
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: please provide an example input and output.

Comment: You can see the input above. Input is numpy array. Output would be suppose: object 1: all the indices of that object eg (1,2), (1, 3)... object2: all indices of that

Comment: Use `np.where`, or just regular numpy indexing but please show some effort

Comment: The objects you can  separate using [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html). To get indices you can for example use `np.argwhere`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you!